# PySimpleGUIQt does not import inside QGIS, DLL not found

Tags: qgis, python, qt, dll

I am trying to run a script inside QGIS that uses pySimpleGUIQt. I can't get it to work, a DLL is not found.

#### Configuration

Win10 64b, QGIS 3.16 (Python 3.7)

#### Steps to reproduce the error

- Open osgeo4w shell, type `py3_env` to setup the python environment
- Type `python -m pip install PySimpleGUIQt`
- Launch QGIS and open Python console, type `import PySimpleGUIQt`

#### Error thrown

```
import PySimpleGUIQt as sg
  File "MY_PERSONNAL_PATH_TO_PYTHON37\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "MY_PERSONNAL_PATH_TO_PYTHON37\site-packages\PySimpleGUIQt\__init__.py", line 2, in 
    from .PySimpleGUIQt import *
  File "MY_PERSONNAL_PATH_TO_PYTHON37\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "MY_PERSONNAL_PATH_TO_PYTHON37\site-packages\PySimpleGUIQt\PySimpleGUIQt.py", line 25, in 
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QLineEdit, QComboBox, QFormLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QListWidget, QDial, QTableWidget
  File "MY_PERSONNAL_PATH_TO_PYTHON37\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted the issue on the QGIS github : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45960
I had a clear answer from the devs : this is not supported. You have to work with Qt and Qt designer inside Qgis and not other Qt-based python libraries.